# Explanation of declaration: id<a_name> delegate;

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I am learning Objective-C and I would like to know what the *meaning* and the *purpose* of the following declaration is:

```
   id<A_specific_name> delegate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means `delegate` is a variable that has the general type `id` and it conforms to `A_specific_name` protocol.

`id` is typedef on `void *`, and a protocol is a concept similar (but not the same exactly) to Java interfaces.

Comment: `id` is not a `void *`. [It is actually](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BAJFBCCJ) `typedef struct objc_object { Class isa; } *id;`

Answer (score 0):

It is an object conform to "A_specific_name" protocol (interface)

You can read [Apple doc on objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-BAJJABHJ)